# Swift - timeIntervalSinceNow Only want to show up to minutes (excluding the seconds part)

Tags: swift, time, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nstimeinterval

I'm using a timeIntervalSinceNow function to determine the difference between a certain time and the current time. I have used the "ZeroFormattingBehaviour" to .DropAll to get rid of any 0's in the date. However I want to make it so the difference doesn't include the seconds difference. For example if the difference is 2 days , 5 hours , 25min and 40 sec I want it to only show 2days,5h,25min. (e.g. excluding the seconds part) Is there any way to do so?

Code is as follows:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Values")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            Values = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

            times = result.valueForKey("time") as! String

            let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd/MM/yy"
            let otherTime = timeFormatter.dateFromString(times)

            let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
            dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.Abbreviated
            dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehavior.DropAll
            let difference = otherTime?.timeIntervalSinceNow
            let diffAbs = abs(difference!)
            let stringDiff = dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(diffAbs)
            // "\n" skips a line in the text
            TimerLabel.text = stringDiff!

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        TimerLabel.text = "There seems to be an error. Please try again later"
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: the date you are using as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the units you want to display

```
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute]
```